# Replace a value in a single column of a dataframe within a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a long list of dataframes. For each dataframe, I want to replace all 0 values in a column with an empty string. I can use the code below to do it, but I was wondering if there is a faster way? There are about 18000 dataframes in the list, so any speed gain is a huge help.

```
for df_player in list_all_dfs:
    df_player["Position"] = df_player["Position"].replace(0, "")
```

Comment: Can you avoid ending up with 18000 dataframes? That sounds like the actual problem...

Comment: Just a proposal: If you could use some memoryview/cast function, then you would only need to tell python that the zero should be interpreted as a char() in which case it should be interpreted as an empty string (at least in C I think that the null string \0 has all bytes zero). So maybe this saves time.

Comment: are those 18000 dfs meant to be combined?

Comment: Dask?  Parallelization.  Ray.io?

Comment: does this `df_player["Index"] = i` give you an expected sequential index values?

Comment: @MKJ please don't edit answers into questions. Instead, post it as an answer so others can vote on it and evaluate it along with any other answers that might appear. Thanks. At any rate, this may be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876), so I suggest providing more context.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it like this now:

```
for i, df_player in enumerate(list_all_dfs):
    df_player["Index"] = i

df_all_players = pd.concat(list_all_dfs)
df_all_players["Position"] = df_all_players["Position"].replace(0, "")
```

Then I can groupby the index to iterate over each player.

Comment: does this `df_player["Index"] = i` give you an expected sequential index values? I don't think so